# Using Metropolis-Hastings method to evaluate an integral in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mcmc

I'm having some trouble using the Metropolis-Hasting's method to evaluate an integral in Matlab. The integral is e^(x^-2) from zero to infinity. The code I have written produces no errors but,
1) I'm not quite sure if it's doing what I want it to be doing
2) Even if it does what I want it to I'm not quite sure how to ''extract'' the value of the integral from the data the code produces

```
clc
clear all

%Parameters for Gaussian proposal distribution N(mu, sigma)
sigma = 1;
mu = 0;

f = @(x) exp(x.^-2); %Target distribution

n = 10000;
step = 1;
x = zeros(1, n); %Storage
x(1) = 1; %Starting point, maximum of function f

for jj = 2:n
xtrial = x(jj-1) + step*normrnd(mu,sigma); %Generates candidate

w = f(xtrial)/f(jj-1);

if w >= 1
    x(jj) = xtrial;
else
    r = rand(1); %Generates uniform for comparison
    if r <= w
        x(jj) = xtrial;
    end
    x(jj) = x(jj-1);
end
end
```

I feel like this problem probably is very simple and that I have just missed something fundamental about this method. Any help would be greatly appreciated since my programming skills are quite basic!

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not defined at x = 0 also in your code you wrote that the maximum of function f is at x = 1, so I assume the integration is from 1 to inf. The value of the integral is the mean of x, and for that i got the result 2.7183 with the following code:

```
    clc
    clear all

    %Parameters for Gaussian proposal distribution N(mu, sigma)
    sigma = 3;
    mu    = 0;
    f     = @(x) double(x>1).*exp(x.^-2); %Target distribution
    n     = 10000;
    step  = 1;
    x     = zeros(1, n); %Storage
    x(1)  = 1;           %Starting point, maximum of function f
    acc   = 0;           % vector to track the acceptance rate

    for jj = 2:n
    xtrial = x(jj-1) + step*normrnd(mu,sigma); %Generates candidate

    w = f(xtrial)/f(x(jj-1));

    if w >= 1
        x(jj) = xtrial;
        acc = acc +1;
    else
        r = rand(1); %Generates uniform for comparison
        if r <= w
            x(jj) = xtrial;
            acc = acc +1;
        end
        x(jj) = x(jj-1);
    end
    end
    plot(x)
    (acc/n)*100
    mean(f(x))
```